# Input for Machine Learning

Tags: python, database, machine-learning, input

I'm using Matlab toolbox and Scikit-learn for implementation of environmental problem. I have different data of different time step but I do not want to concatenate all files together since each of which is for the specific time step. What is your solution to define a folder containing 1000 files and how to define for the machine to read those files consecutively?

I've tried by employing toolbox and scikit-learn to read each file as an input but I could not be able to read all files as a consecutive input.

Comment: Have you tried using the [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) module? I think it can solve your problem.

Comment: It does not work. first I tried:                                                                                 `l = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir('.')) if f.startswith('config')]

for i, d in enumerate(l):
    a = np.loadtxt(d)
    num = os.path.splitext(d)[0]
    a = np.delete(a,1,0)
b = np.savetxt(a)`
but It did not work and then I used `for` but I could not

Comment: when you read new file to `a` then you replace content from previous one. You would have to create empty list/array at start and `append` data from `a` to this list.